# Strange initial empty space writing data into a file in c++

Tags: c++, file, stringstream

I am facing a strange issue with my application, and although I have tried several solutions, none have solved my problem.

My *c++* application generates a set of files with custom data. So far, the code seems to work fine, and the files are generated correctly, except the first one. The expected format of the files is the following:

```
@Header
@Line1E1,Line1E2,Line1E3
@Line2E1,Line2E2,Line1E3
```

However, I have noticed a strange empty space on the first line of the first generated file (and only the first one):

```
   @Header
@Line1E1,Line1E2,Line1E3
@Line2E1,Line2E2,Line1E3
```

Since the code is the same for all the files, I am wondering what dit it go wrong, but so far I have not been able to detect the root of my problem.

The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
/* Variables */
std::ofstream Fil;
std::stringstream ss;

ss.precision (10);
ss.width (10);
ss.setf (ios::fixed);

for (int Inx = 0; Inx < MaxInx; Inx++) {

  sprintf (FilNam, "%i-ExportFile.txt", Inx);
  Fil.open(std::string (FilNam).c_str (), std::ofstream::out);

  SavSta = Fil.is_open ();

  if (SavSta) {
    ss << "@Header"        << "\n";
    ss << "@Matrix name: " << MtxName  << "\n";
    ss << /* Matrix data goes here */ << "\n";

    Fil << ss.rdbuf ();
    ss.str(std::string ());
    ss.clear ();
  }
  Fil.close ();
}
```

Comment: If you write just that first line to the file what does the debugger say?

Comment: The debugger shows the initial blank space at the stringstream, but only on the first execution of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is coming from :

```
ss.width(10);
```

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/)

> If the standard width of the representation is shorter than the field width, the representation is padded with fill characters

Just remove it and you'll be OK.

Comment: Indeed, it seems this was the cause of the problem. Should I guess then that executing `ss.clear()` clears these settings (`ss.width()`, `ss.setf()`, and `ss.precision()`)?

Comment: @MikelUrkia No, this will only reset the errors flags, positioned if an error occured while reading/writing from your stream, use `ss.unsetf()`. As for `width()`I don't really think you need it given your file format.